# Upgrade from 5.10 to 5.12 contact images no longer appearing

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I'm wondering if anyone is experiencing a similar issue. 
I upgraded to 5.12 this morning and now it seems contact images are not displaying...

I grabbed the url 
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ffile&reset=1&filename=imageName.jpg&mime-type=image/jpeg&reauth=1

To see if I could access the image, but it downloads an unreadable file.

I have tried deleting a contact image and uploading a different one with the same results, and it does seem as though the images exist on my file system....

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: I've done a little more digging and it doesn't look like a civicrm_file record is being created in the DB.

Comment: I've done a little more digging and realised the contact image is stored directly in the civicrm_contact table. 
the URL for the contact image is stored, however when I follow the link I get the following message 
You do not have permission to access this content.

So I guess its a privacy setting somewhere? 

civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&amp;q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fimagefile&amp;photo=image.jpg

Comment: Are you logged in as user 1 or administrator user?

Comment: I tried as admin and as a generic user.

Comment: Can you check if the user role has permission to view uploaded images?

Comment: Looks like it, although its entirely possible I'm missing something,

Comment: I've checked, and given every possible role permission to view uploaded images, and still no love.

Comment: Can you try to replicate on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: Hi Pradeep thanks for your help with this. I can't seem to replicate the issue. 
I created custom fields,  a smart group, and a membership type, created a profile, and tried editing the profile and images (both the specific contact image_URL and custom images) upload and display with no issues. 
I think perhaps I've done something stupid. ;) But I'm not sure how to right this wrong. Is there a way to reset security settings to defaults? Or start with a fresh civicrm install?

Comment: Ok. I had a redirect after submit set for the profile. - when I removed it, added an image and tried to submit I got the following error 
`Warning: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php on line 1187

Comment: Warning: getimagesize(): Failed to enable crypto in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php on line 1187 Warning: getimagesize(https://iakpcivicrm.local/member-dashboard/edit-practitioner-listing/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fimagefile&photo=figure_2acf5cf3137af5e29362ab3e59724d13.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php on line 1187`

Comment: Your SSL certificate is not verified, contact your ssl provider or system admin to get it verified

Comment: Thanks - It's a problem with the SSL in Flywheel Local - incase anyone ever develops using the Local App.