# Contact URL image display in civiCRM 5.12.4

Tags: images, ssl

I'm using civicrm v5.12.4

a while back I made this post. - [Upgrade from 5.10 to 5.12 contact images no longer appearing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29278/upgrade-from-5-10-to-5-12-contact-images-no-longer-appearing)

As I was having issues with contact images displaying. It seemed the issue I was having then was that I was developing locally, with a locally created SSL certificate.

The Contact Images are really important to this project and so I got some hosting with a ssl certificate and set up wordpress and civicrm

I installed it originally on a hosting platform without enforcing Https.
Then I enforced https and found I needed to edit the civicrm.settings.php file and replce all instances of http:// in the file, to make the site work.

Now, everything seems to be working smoothly, with the exception of contact images. I'm not getting any error messages, the images are just displaying as broken image icons.

This happens whether I try to attach an image via the edit contact civicrm pages or a profile page.

Does any one have tips for how I could trouble shoot this?

[image]

Comment: do you see any link appearing on bottom-left of the browser when you hover the mouse pointer on the broken image? can you paste the screenshot of that?

Comment: I can't seem to post a screen shot in a reply. But the link that is being generated for the image is  :
https://iakpversion2.flywheelsites.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ffile&reset=1&filename=Capture1_c20afbccc804ce82acb65eac507892a1.PNG&mime-type=image/png 
If you click this link it downloads a .png file that appears to be damaged or incomplete. It's not just this file though. I've tried with numerous images.

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working. I did a clean install of everything,

Followed the wordpress civicrm install instructions for clean URLS

Enforced SSL using the siteground hosting built in tools

Enforced SSL in civicrm

Then in the wordpress permalinks settings removed any reference to index.php.

Not totally sure whether this combination of things was essential or what caused the issue in the first place. But the key was removing index.php from the wordpress permalinks. It was interrupting a lot of civicrm pages